# Google App Engine cannot find lib from appengine_config

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a flask application on google cloud. In spite of following their instructions, whenever I start dev server, it cannot find the library given `vendor.add('lib')`. How to fix this?

```
sudo /google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml > file
INFO     2017-10-10 20:20:04,276 devappserver2.py:115] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-10-10 20:20:04,338 api_server.py:299] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53496
WARNING  2017-10-10 20:20:04,338 dispatcher.py:285] Your python27 micro version is below 2.7.12, our current production version.
INFO     2017-10-10 20:20:04,343 dispatcher.py:224] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-10-10 20:20:04,345 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
/deploy_10oct/lib
ERROR    2017-10-10 20:20:11,913 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "deploy_10oct/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import h5py
ImportError: No module named h5py
INFO     2017-10-10 20:20:11,919 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Directory structure

```
ls 
app.yaml    
env         
lame.pyc        
main.pyc        
templates
appengine_config.py         
lib         
requirements.txt    
uploads
appengine_config.pyc    
lame.py         
main.py         
static
```

Comment: Could you share your `appengine_config.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `lib` dir inside your application and install your dependencies in that dir (not on your system's python installation). From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous
>      step. For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

Comment: I have done exactly that. I wrote a small program which just calls hello world and imported h5py onto it and it throws the same error. The error is on wsgi line 263. How do I debug that now?

Comment: Standalone apps != GAE apps. Standalone apps use libraries from your local python path, GAE apps use libraries they contain inside. You should run your GAE app inside the devserver. You could also try to  teach your standalone program to use the GAE app libs instead, but IMHO that's just a waste of time.